# How should posts on meta be marked as irrelevant, if something changes?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

For instance, everything having to do with rep recalc that was posted more than a couple months ago is now irrelevant and hard to figure out - I needed to go to chat to find out that the whole thing was fixed. i searched on meta, but could not find the post about the changes.

Perhaps in this case we can close all questions tagged rep-recalc from before march of this year - but that may decrease the reputation of the askers unfairly.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to implement this in a way that is scalable?

Answer (score 2):

Why not close the questions as "Too Localized"?

> **This question is unlikely to help any future visitors**; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, **a specific moment in time**, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

(emphasis mine)

If it's a question about a feature or issue that no longer exists, it's certainly not going to help any future visitors.

Comment: That's true - but then those that find the question will not find the link to the information. This means they will find different, but non-closed information. It's better than nothing, but not a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could a flag be added on Meta with a link to the change in how the system works? Perhaps the behavior could be simply to add a link to the blog post / question / whatever that points out why it's no longer relevant. I don't think it should be closed as exact duplicate, but a similar behavior could be applied. (It should not cause reputation to disappear, for instance.)

On the other hand, this is a very non-scalable way of fixing the problem.

Comment: I probably should have marked this as discussion. (Tags changed!) I don't think it's a scalable solution, and if better ideas exist, they would be preferable.